# Show json array data to textview using retrofit

Tags: java, android, json

Can someone help me ? , The textview doesn't show data .. At this time , I just trying to fetch data from json file in localhost

Now when i do

```
   `Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RestAPI service = retrofit.create(RestAPI.class);
    Call<Models> call = service.getDataQuest();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Models>() { //Asyncronous Request
                     @Override
                     public void onResponse(Call<Models> call, Response<Models> response) {
                         try {
                             loading.dismiss(); 

                             Models m = response.body();

                             String q = m.getQuestion().get(0).getIsiP();
                             String q1 = m.getQuestion().get(1).getIsiP();
                             String q2 = m.getQuestion().get(3).getIsiP();
                             String q3 = m.getQuestion().get(4).getIsiP();

                             tv1.setText(q);
                             tv2.setText(q1);
                             tv3.setText(q2);
                             tv4.setText(q3);

                         }catch (Exception e){
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                     }

                 }
    );
}`
```

API

```
public interface RestAPI {

@GET("survey.json")
Call<Models> getDataQuest();}
```

Comment: Most likely you're getting an exception. Please post whatever stacktrace is printed in your logcat

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct? What device you're using - emulator or real device? Could you write down what base url you're using? Could you provide an exception if it's available as @JorgeMendez asked above?

Comment: 08-24 08:58:34.444 15038-15038/com.example.dilaga.survey_apps_velocite V/TextView: stopSelectionActionMode()

Like this one , but it loops 8 times in my logcat @JorgeMendez

Comment: I don't think so , I am using real device @Seishin

private static String ROOT_URL = "http://192.168.173.1/";

I am using localhost as server

Comment: Maybe both of you can help me with volley , i think it's better than fixed my retro